# php retrieve curl_setopt POSTFIELDS string

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

Is there any way to retrieve the curl_setopt POSTFIELDS string which I had posted to the site after the curl_multi_exec($mh, $running) command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep that data together with the individual resources:

```
$handles = array();
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $data = 'whatever';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $handles[$url] = array(
        'ch' => $ch,
        'data' => $data,
    );
}
```

This keeps the cURL handles and data together in a single structure that you can later use to inspect.

```
foreach($handles as $url => $data) {
    // $url is the page you requested for this particular handle
    // $data['data'] contains the data that goes with it
    $body = curl_multi_getcontent($data['ch']);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $data['ch']);
    curl_close($data['ch']);
}
```